# How to evaulate a expression in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have a math expression i.e. 1 * 3 in string form, which i want to evaluate at run time, i have studied NCalc and it is quit useful for windows application but in phone it doesn't work, give error of mscorelib. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [Jace](https://github.com/pieterderycke/Jace) (Just Another Calculation Engine). It supports mobile platforms as well as Xamarin projects.

Comment: Jace.Net doesnt work with windows phone 8.1... I tried to install it.

Comment: @SyedWajahatKareem - Are you trying to build a Universal App or a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app?

Comment: Its universal App, i chose a blank app. Also i am quit inspired looking your work.